# Flash input text field only accepts characters already used somewhere on the stage. What's happening?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

On the stage I have an input field (classic text, input text) with **no filters** and **no restrictions** and yet, when I try to type something in it, I can only use characters that are already on the stage somwhere else.

For example, I have a few other labels on the stage with the strings '125' and 'HB'. In my input field I can now type any string containing those characters, like 'H52B' or '121212', but I just can't use any other characters! If I press '4' or 'K' on my keyboard, nothing happens!

I am sure there is nothing happening to this input field in actionscript and there are no filters on it. This problem may have something to do with the fact that I got this fla from a designer and upon opening it, I got a message saying something about fonts not being on my machine and converting to system defaults. Could it have something to do with that?

I'm using flash cs5.5 and actionscript 3.

Comment: Check if the designer embedded only some characters of your font and embed all the remaining characters you eventually need.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just posted   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the designer embedded only some characters of your font and embed all the remaining characters you eventually need.